matplotlib and yahoo finance api not setting date correctly
I'm trying to implement a button where if the user clicks on it, it will show the stocks change in price over the last 24 hours, in the chance where the market was closed, it will keep going back a day until it finds data, meaning the market is now open. The issue I am having is when i press the 1D button, the graph doesn't show any lines and the x-axis is showing dates that are not within the last 24 hours (it starts from 2022 and goes up until 2026). Below are the related functions. Any help on why this happens is greatly appreciated
def set_interval_1d(self):
        # Calculate start and end dates for the past 24 hours
        end_date = datetime.today()
        start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=1)

        # Retrieve stock data for the entered symbol
        search_text = self.search_bar.text()
        self.searched_stock = search_text  # Save the searched stock name
        data = pd.DataFrame()

        # Check if data is available for the past 24 hours
        while data.empty and start_date < end_date:
            start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

            # Check if the market is open for the given date
            if not yf.Ticker(search_text).history(start=start_date_str, end=start_date_str)['Close'].empty:
                data = yf.download(search_text, start=start_date_str, end=end_date)

            start_date += timedelta(days=1)

        # Check if data is not empty
        # if not data.empty:
            # Check if 'Adj Close' column is present
        #     if 'Adj Close' in data.columns:
        #         # Format stock information
        #         stock_info = data.head().to_string()
        #         print('STOCK INFORMATION:', stock_info)
        #     else:
        #         print("No 'Adj Close' column found in the data")
        #         return
        # else:
        #     print('STOCK NAME:', search_text)
        #     print("No data available for the past 24 hours")
        #     return

        # Update the button colors based on the trend
        trend_color = 'limegreen' if data['Adj Close'].iloc[-1] > data['Adj Close'].iloc[0] else 'red'
        self.update_button_colors(trend_color)
        # Update the graph with the new data
        self.plot_stock_graph(data, search_text)

def plot_stock_graph(self, data, symbol):
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

        # Plot the closing prices
        data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
        plt.plot(data.index, data['Adj Close'], label=f'{symbol} Adj Close Price', color='black')

        # Determine the trend
        if data['Adj Close'].iloc[-1] > data['Adj Close'].iloc[0]:
            trend_color = 'limegreen'
        else:
            trend_color = 'red'

        # Plot the trend line
        plt.plot(data.index, data['Adj Close'], color=trend_color, linestyle='-')
        print('DATA INDEX:', data.index)
        plt.title(f'{symbol} Adj Close Price')
        plt.xlabel('Date')
        plt.ylabel('Price')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.legend()
        self.update_button_colors(trend_color)
        self.canvas.figure.clear()
        self.canvas.figure = plt.gcf()
        self.canvas.draw()


